# does fuseesb have a similar UI framework concept to wso2 carbon?

Tags: wso2, fuseesb

I've been looking at WSO2 Carbon as an OSGi application platform providing the following functionality:

- Services can be deployed as OSGi components (backend and frontend/UI)
- A Service UI components can be hosted (snapped) into the Carbon UI
- A Service can use Carbon User Management database for authentication and authorization

Does fuseesb have a similar UI concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using fuse ESB for about 6 months, I'm very happy with it.

Services are easily deployed as OSGi components - these are quite easily configured and deployed as fuse `features`. Fuse `profiles` then contain property files that define which `features` are deployed to your OSGi containers.

Although I haven't used every feature, I haven't seen a similar UI concept for hosting / snapping.

For authentication and authorization there are various approaches - one nice solution is to use Apache zookeeper (a key/value store) as a basis for a simple user management component that can be available to all your services.